# i am unable to run jenkins-cli through Docker

Tags: unix, docker, jenkins

I Need to pass the pom.xml file which is used to build on my Jenkins server.

For that I used code

```
 WORKDIR /jenkins-cli
 COPY jenkins-cli-wrapper.sh .

 ENV JENKINS_URL "localhost:8080"
 ENV PRIVATE_KEY "/ssh/id_rsa"
 VOLUME /ssh

 ENTRYPOINT ["./jenkins-cli-wrapper.sh"]
 CMD ["help"] `
```

**I'm building this using base os ubuntu 14.04**
**also I have downloaded the JDK, Maven, Jenkins before running the above command**

When I run my code everything will be downloaded and the error is

```
Step 22/27 : COPY jenkins-cli wrapper.sh .
COPY failed: stat /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder551301078/jenkins-cli: no such file or directory
```

I have tried all solutions ref ring  to above error.

MY QUESTIONS ARE:

1. How can I resolve this?
2. Further steps to run jenkins-cli when I run the image.